# Trying to merge two unsorted arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written code in javascript trying to return a single sorted array by giving two sortedarray inputs.

```js
function finalArray(arr1, arr2) {
  const mergedArray = [];
  if (arr1.length === 0) {
    return arr2;
  }
  if (arr2.length === 0) {
    return arr1;
  }
  let arr1Item = arr1[0];
  let arr2Item = arr2[0];
  let i = 1;
  let j = 1;

  while (arr1Item || arr2Item) {
    if (arr2Item === undefined || arr1Item < arr2Item) {
      mergedArray.push(arr1Item);
      arr1Item = arr1[i];
      i++;
    } else {
      mergedArray.push(arr2Item);
      arr2Item = arr2[j];
      j++;
    }
  }
  return mergedArray
}

console.log(finalArray([2, 6, 4, 10], [15, 1, 5, 33]));
```

Can anyone help with how to merge unsorted arrays?

Comment: `arr2Item === "undefiend"` will not work...

Comment: Yeah even though not woring `arr2Item === undefined`

Comment: simply use `Array.concat(arr1,arr2).sort((a,b)=>a-b)`

Comment: can you explain according to the post because I'm trying to do without using any built-in functions?

Comment: Walk through your logic manually on paper. You will end up going through all of first array because they are all less than first element of second array. Then when no element is left from first array  will just start pushing second array in it's existing order

Comment: Is this a partial implementation of Merge Sort? Or can you just `return [ ...a, ...b ].sort()`?

Comment: @charlietfl   got it, but array2 has `1` which is less than array1 elements. where I need to change the code?

Comment: You won't get past that 15 to see the 1 until first array is all done though. Then you are always comparing undefined to the next element in second array

Comment: @tadman I'm implementing without using any built-in functions.

Comment: So basically implementing Merge Sort, fair. Please state any unusual requirements like this up front, though.

Comment: @charlietfl  Thank you so much I got it that  If we passed sorted arrays as inputs then the function works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Merge your two arrays first, then perform the sort?

```
const arr1 = [2, 6, 4, 10];
const arr2 = [10, 1, 5, 33];
const newArray = ([...arr1, ...arr2]);
newArray.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
console.log(newArray);
```

Expected output: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 10, 33]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are comparing every two pair of data and pushing smaller one.
First try to sort each sub array without entering compare process for mixing.
After the sub arrays are being sorted, then compare to each other.